# .htaccess RewriteRule Not Working for Digits Only

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is what I have in my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

This redirects any non-existent directory request to my index page. This works for `www.site.com/AAA` , `www.site.com/A1` , `www.site.com/1A`, but not `www.site.com/1` or `www.site.com/123`

Basically, it does not work for requests that are only digits.

Any thoughts about this would be greatly appreciated.

I also tried

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]*$ ./index.php
```

But that does not work either.

I have Google as my default search engine, so when I type `www.site.com/1234`, and the page is not found, I get directed to a Google results page that says "Your Search for www.site.com/1234 did not match any documents" -  I assume this is the same as a 404 but then Google takes over and treats it like a search.

EDIT
Did not occur to me this could be a browser issue. Now I tried on FF Mac and IE Win and it works correctly. Does not work correctly on Safari Mac or Safari iOS. I just sent the link to some more people to try.

Comment: You have not tried to make it work only for a more specific URI by what you are showing. Have you made any attempt at this?

Comment: Is this the only rule or you have more rules too?

Comment: That is everything that is in the .htaccess file

Comment: Have you tried checking on `REQUEST_FILENAME` instead?

Comment: @Prix - nope, still getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

I just used you rule on an empty .htaccess on a default virtualhost, requesting this

```
http://test.local/1
```

and this is the rewrite.log for that request

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2014:10:31:14 +0800] [test.local/sid#a89a80][rid#7fc63c002970/initial] (3) [perdir /mnt/webs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /mnt/webs/test/1 -> 1
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2014:10:31:14 +0800] [test.local/sid#a89a80][rid#7fc63c002970/initial] (3) [perdir /mnt/webs/test/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri '1'
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2014:10:31:14 +0800] [test.local/sid#a89a80][rid#7fc63c002970/initial] (2) [perdir /mnt/webs/test/] rewrite '1' -> './index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2014:10:31:14 +0800] [test.local/sid#a89a80][rid#7fc63c002970/initial] (3) [perdir /mnt/webs/test/] add per-dir prefix: ./index.php -> /mnt/webs/test/./index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2014:10:31:14 +0800] [test.local/sid#a89a80][rid#7fc63c002970/initial] (2) [perdir /mnt/webs/test/] strip document_root prefix: /mnt/webs/test/./index.php -> /./index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2014:10:31:14 +0800] [test.local/sid#a89a80][rid#7fc63c002970/initial] (1) [perdir /mnt/webs/test/] internal redirect with /./index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2014:10:31:14 +0800] [test.local/sid#a89a80][rid#7fc63c00be98/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /mnt/webs/test/] strip per-dir prefix: /mnt/webs/test/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2014:10:31:14 +0800] [test.local/sid#a89a80][rid#7fc63c00be98/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /mnt/webs/test/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2014:10:31:14 +0800] [test.local/sid#a89a80][rid#7fc63c00be98/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /mnt/webs/test/] pass through /mnt/webs/test/index.php
```

I got the index.php file. It should work

Although, a minor suggestion is to change this

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

to this

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

Is not a big change on your code, but it removes one internal step for the server since it won't have to resolve the './' part.

One thing you can do, to confirm that things are working as expected, is to have and index.php file with just this:

```
var_dump( $_SERVER );
```

There you should see this bits

```
'REDIRECT_URL' => string '/1' (length=2)
'REQUEST_URI' => string '/1' (length=2)
'SCRIPT_NAME' => string '/index.php' (length=10)
```

That would mean that the request was /1 but the file being executed is index.php, which means that the rewrite worked. If you get something different, it's a start for debugging

Comment: I understand it works on your server, but it is not working on mine. I get a "Not Found" message and get redirected to a Google page, which I assume is just my browser's default default action when the page does not exist.

Comment: That is not something that should happen. You have something doing that redirection. Check the access and rewrite log and check what is happening. Clear the logs, restart the server and try to load the url ending with /1 before loading anything else. After you have done that, post both logs (access and rewrite) here. Check also your hosts file.

Comment: the not found is shown on the browser? then automatically you get redirected? Does that happen in more than one browser?

Comment: Did not occur to me this could be a browser issue. Now I tried on FF Mac and IE Win and it works correctly. Does not work on Safari Mac or Safari iOS. I just sent the link to some more people to try.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`FallbackResource /index.php`

instead and remove your rewrite rules. Reportedly works with Apache 2.2.16+ (I've not tested with numbers but worth a try).

Comment: This still gets me the same result. Using all digits pushes me to a Google page that says "you search did not match any documents" -  all other results are the same as in my original post.

Comment: Sounds like your browser's "Omnibox" might be at fault. What happens if you enter the address including the protocol? eg `http://www.example.com/1234`

Comment: Ah that works... not really the solution I want, but maybe that is how it needs to be?

Comment: I'd say it looks like a browser bug. Is it Chrome you're using? I've noticed Chrome can start misinterpretting URLs based on your browsing history, so you could trying clearing that out. I'd also try the problem address in other browsers on your computer (or browsers on other computers/devices) to double-check this is absolutely not related to your server config.